# What's the purpose of GRANT DML rights on view in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, permissions

In SQL Server 2005, it is possible to grant some rights on **views** - I do not understand this concept.

The `SELECT` and `REFERENCE` rights are obvious, but I am perplexed about `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`. I am sure that they are there for a reason but I do not see it.

Maybe those rights are propagated to the tables referenced by the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the name, views can be updatable in SQL Server. Paraphrasing [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) (the "Updatable views" section")

> You can modify the data of an underlying base table through a view, as long as the following conditions are true:
>
> - Any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements,
>     must reference columns from only one base table.
> - The columns being modified in the view must directly reference the underlying data in the table columns. The columns cannot be
>     derived in any other way, such as through the following:
> - An aggregate function: AVG, COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, GROUPING, STDEV, STDEVP, VAR, and VARP.
> - A computation. The column cannot be computed from an expression that uses other columns. Columns that are formed by using
>     the set operators UNION, UNION ALL, CROSSJOIN, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT
>     amount to a computation and are also not updatable.
> - The columns being modified are not affected by GROUP BY, HAVING, or DISTINCT clauses.
> - TOP is not used anywhere in the select_statement of the view together with the WITH CHECK OPTION clause.

Further, you can have `INSTEAD OF` triggers on views that bypass these restrictions.

TL;DR - there are many scenarios in which you can execute DML against a view. Having permission governing who can do those operations makes sense given that.

Comment: You are right, I searched for VIEW permissions but did't check in the general view documentation. I tried to update some views in some occasion, but most of my views do not comply with the updatable view requirements, therefore my experiments failed and I was even more sure that cannot be done.